# Working with document Libraries based on UniqueID REST API

Tags: document-library, office-365, folder

Is it possible to work with the document library with UniqueID/Guids rather than using `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl`?

Say if I wanted to upload a file to a folder, could this be done using the Unique Id instead of the relative path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, [SP.Web object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245288(v=office.15).aspx#methods) in SharePoint 2013/Online exposes the following methods:

1) [Web.GetFolderById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfolderbyid(v=office.15).ASPX)

REST endpoint: `/_api/web/GetFolderById('<folder unique id>')`

2) [Web.GetFileById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfilebyid(v=office.15).aspx)

REST endpoint: `/_api/web/GetFileById('<file unique id>')`

Comment: That just saved my life, thanks!

Just one comment though, for SharePoint newbies like me, the base url has to be the one for the site. Like https://myorg.sharepoint.com/the-site-name/_api/web/GetFileById(<whatever>).

Comment: Thanks a million! i've been trying to delete files by filename using "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + fileToDelete +"')"     It works in most cases but i couldn't figure out how to process special characters like #.  Your method works everytime!

Comment: can't find this `GetFileById` in the CSOM C# dll. is this available only in REST API and SSOM ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the document library using the title and then perform the upload

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='true')?@TargetLibrary='LibraryName'&@TargetFileName='Target File Name'
```

[More](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/04/20/uploading-files-using-the-rest-api-and-client-side-techniques.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to reference folders by the Guid instead of using the path?