# Can i get content OR download file by GUID?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, document, microsoft-graph

I want to get content OR download  file by GUID.
I can work when use APIs below to get ServerRelativeUrl and use which to download file. But I must call three API:

```
https://your-site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('document')/items?$top=1&$filter= UniqueId eq 'GUID'
```

and

```
https://your-site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('document')/items/GetById(1)/file
```

I just want to call an API by GUID.

Hope everyone can help.

Comment: Try using URL like this and see if it works for you: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId={F841E2A9-A1E3-4941-A0A1-8A9080ED6756}`. **Reference**: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/11/10/sharepoint-online-download-files-using-json-formatting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get file using SharePoint API calls only, try using API call like:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/GetFileById('<file unique id>')
```

**Reference**: [Working with document Libraries based on UniqueID REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119202/working-with-document-libraries-based-on-uniqueid-rest-api)

---

**Additional**:

You can also try using URL like this and see if it works for you:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId={F841E2A9-A1E3-4941-A0A1-8A9080ED6756}
```

Where `F841E2A9-A1E3-4941-A0A1-8A9080ED6756` is unique ID of your file.

**Reference**: [SharePoint Online: Download files using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/11/10/sharepoint-online-download-files-using-json-formatting/)

Comment: Thank you very much, its work for me.

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked for you.

Comment: Thank you, bro.  i did that.

Comment: You're welcome!